# Incorrect Content-Length for a file (Request Entity Too Large 413)

Tags: python, https, streaming

A server receives a file succesfuly if it's small enough. Otherwise, it returns an error of "`Request Entity Too Large Error 413`". This is not a mine server, so I'm unable to deal with it directly.

I'm pretty sure it depends of `Content-Length` http header (in fact, this is **https** connection if it matters).

```
conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection("www.site.com")
conn.connect()
conn.putrequest("POST", path)
conn.putheader("Content-Type", "some type")
conn.putheader("Content-Length", str(os.path.getsize(file_name)))
conn.endheaders()
```

Even if I try to send file chunk by chunk for a big file (too big)

```
chunk_size = 1024

while True:
  try:
    chunk = f.read(chunk_size)
    if not chunk:
      break
    conn.send(chunk)
  except Exception as e:
    break
```

it failed, while on the small files it worked well.

If I manually make Content-Type smaller, it seems(!) to work, at least the error of "`Request Entity Too Large Error 413`" from a server disappers. But it doesn't work completely because, probably, the format of a file (that's an audio file) becomes broken this way and the server simply is unable to proccess this file by saying that ("wrong format of a file"):

```
  fake_total_size = 1024*10 # it's smaller than a real file size for sure
  conn.putheader("Content-Length", str(fake_total_size))
  f = open(file_name)
  chunk_size = fake_total_size
  chunk = f.read(chunk_size)
  conn.send(chunk)
```

What am I doing wrong and how to solve it?

I guess it has to deal with reading and sending big files by some portions of acceptable size with correct Content-Length value? Or streaming uploading, perhaps?